# Would K-means be Appropriate to Use with Four or More Variables?

Tags: dataset, statistics, visualization, k-means, normalization

Just a general question that I'm trying to mentally visualize. I'm fairly new to using k-means clustering and have used it before on two variables, which creates a 2-D plot of points. I also know, although I haven't done it before, that you can plot a k-means cluster with three variables utilizing the x, y, and z axes. But now I'm currently in a position where I have four variables, normalized by their z-scores, in which I'm not sure how to use the k-means clustering appropriately. Should I be using a k-means cluster in this circumstance?

Thanks

Comment: Sure! There's nothing stopping you from doing K-means using $n$ variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use k-Means clustering in all the dimensions you need. This technique is based on a k number of centroids that self-adjust to the data and "cluster" them. The k centroids can be defined in any number of dimensions.

If you want to find the optimal number of centroids, the **elbow method** is still the best. You iterate the algorithm changing the value of k each time, and record how much error the clustering is producing; once you're done you plot the error levels against each k value and check the optimal k visually. There is plenty of tutorial on it, you can start [here](https://blog.cambridgespark.com/how-to-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-for-k-means-clustering-14f27070048f) for example.

Answer (score 0):

By default K-Means assign a particular data point(or say sample) to that centroid which is having minimum Euclidean distance.
So ideally K-Means should work for any number of clusters/centroids.

> Since you have normalized your dataset by Z-score, I think you have to
>   be very precise in your calculations and set hyperparameter
>   accordingly otherwise it's possible that you will not observe any
>   movement of data point across different centroids.